# Clone SSD or move windows settings over?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, clone

I'm getting a new computer with a bigger and faster SSD (256GB vs 64GB). Should I do a clean install of Windows 7 and move the settings over, or should I try to clone the old SSD? Which is best, and how do I do it?

Comment: Are you going to have the exact same setup?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to keep my current setup if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I always suggest that you start fresh, it is a great way to clean things up.  The most simple way to do this is by using the Windows Easy Transfer tool:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer

Make sure you have your basic drivers on a flash drive before starting.  At least the network driver.  This way you will have internet access if you need to download any additional drivers.

Of course if you still wish to clone the drive instead of going through the trouble of a complete reinstall, you can always use CloneZilla:

http://clonezilla.org/

There is a simple guide on it here:
http://www.mindworkshop.info/windows/windows-adjustments-back-up-your-windows-installation/

Answer (score 1):

SInce you want to keep your current setup cloning is the best option, but you will have to expand the partition after cloning to keep the full disk size